# Ssh key on github

Tags: git, github, ssh, .netrc

Whenever I want to commit something on my repository, I have to type

```
ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_git_key_file
```

Is there a way to not do that every time I want to commit something? 
I want to use a .netrc file with this inside instead of the ssh keys:

```
machine github.com
login <login_github>
password <password_github>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens because your SSH daemon is not running. You can fix that by running:

```
eval `ssh-agent -s`
ssh-add ~/.ssh/my_git_key_file
```

Then it shouldn't ask you again about the SSH password.

If you want to use the `.netrc` file, use the HTTPS repository url:

```
git remote set-url origin https://github.com/owner/repo.git
```